# How to check general conditions?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I have translated a code from Matlab (array orientation) to Java(OOP). The problem appeared when I have to translate this feature of Matlab:

```
min_omegaF_restricted=min(omegaF(p>cost));
```

Here, `omegaF` is a vector with the net worth of each firm.
`p` a vector of prices for each firm.
`cost` a vector of costs for each firm.
The above calculate the minimal net worth of survivor firms with demanded price higher than their costs.
In java can be translated to:

```
double min_omegaF_restricted=Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
for(int f=0; f<F; f++){
    Firm fo=firms.get(f);
    if(fo.p>fo.cost)
        min_omegaF_restricted=Math.min(min_omegaF_restricted, fo.omegaF);
}
```

Is there a option to generalize this kind of sentence to whatever condition (`fo.p>fo.cost`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Functional interfaces and lambdas in Java 8 make this simple and easy on the eyes. Create a [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) which tests an object and returns a boolean value.

```
Predicate<Firm> predicate = firm -> firm.p > firm.cost;
```

Then you can defer to the predicate in the loop like so:

```
double min_omegaF_restricted=Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
for(int f=0; f<F; f++){
    Firm fo=firms.get(f);
    if(predicate.test(fo))
        min_omegaF_restricted=Math.min(min_omegaF_restricted, fo.omegaF);
}
```

What's more, with the new streaming API you can express the whole computation functionally without the explicit `for` loop.

```
double min_omegaF_restricted = firms.stream()
    .filter(predicate)
    .mapToDouble(f -> f.omegaF)
    .min()
    .orElse(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

Comment: Wow, very good, this kind of new features will be very suitable for my problem. Thank you very much.